# 802.1q vlan naming in Debian 10

Tags: networking, debian, vlan

Upgrading router and facing problem VLAN interfaces does not go up (error "Unknown interface" if perform 'ifup vlanxxx') if vlans are defined in following manner:

```
auto vlanxxx
iface vlanxxx inet static
vlan-raw-device eno1
address 192.168.0.1
netmask 255.255.255.0
```

but it does load if I change VLAN names definition in following manner:

```
auto eno1.xxx
iface eno1.xxx inet static
address 192.168.0.1
netmask 255.255.255.0
```

in https://wiki.debian.org/NetworkConfiguration#Manual_config both VLAN naming convention are described, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You are most certainly lacking the add-on package [`vlan`](https://packages.debian.org/buster/vlan):

> ifupdown integration for vlan configuration
>
> This package contains integration scripts for configuring vlan
> interfaces via ifupdown (/etc/network/interfaces). For further details
> see [vlan-interfaces(5)](https://manpages.debian.org/buster/vlan/vlan-interfaces.5) man page in this package.

It also suggests that its VLAN support is limited and one should use one's own *iproute2* commands anyway.

Without this add-on package, [`vlan-raw-device`](https://manpages.debian.org/buster/vlan/vlan-interfaces.5#EXTRA_IFACE_OPTIONS) is not a valid command, while [`interfaces(5)`](https://manpages.debian.org/buster/ifupdown/interfaces.5#VLAN_INTERFACES) still documents direct support for the interface.VID scheme.

---

Historically the main use of this package was to provide the [`vconfig`](https://manpages.debian.org/buster/vlan/vconfig.8) command: it's still provided, but this command has been entirely replaced by `ip link` commands in the add-on scripts. Now, its main use is to provide the additional VLAN-related commands for [`ifupdown`](https://packages.debian.org/buster/ifupdown). About the same goes with the package `bridge-utils`: not really for its obsolete (but strangely still widely in use) [`brctl`](https://manpages.debian.org/buster/bridge-utils/brctl.8) command but for its `ifupdown` [configuration add-on](https://manpages.debian.org/buster/bridge-utils/bridge-utils-interfaces.5), which still does rely on `brctl` though.

---

There is also a [complete reimplementation](https://cumulusnetworks.github.io/ifupdown2/) available with the [`ifupdown2`](https://packages.debian.org/buster/ifupdown2) package which doesn't rely on any obsolete command nor add-on and is mostly (but not completely) compatible, and there might possibly be in the future a new Debian implementation called [`ifupdown-ng`](https://salsa.debian.org/debian/ifupdown-ng).

Comment: Look like I have it installed: command `apt-get install vlan` give me `vlan is already the newest version (2.0.5).`

Comment: Just found if prepend this line `post-up ip link add name vlan46 link eno1 type vlan id 46` and this line
`pre-down ip link delete dev vlan46 type vlan` before vlan definition and reboot machine, than VLAN is up. I can perform `ifdown vlan46` but nothing more untill next reboot. ifup vlan46` cause error 'cannot find device "vlan46"'